# How to use Keyboard Key.Down to navigate items across ListView in a universal app

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I have a ListView,what I want is to move from one ListViewItem to an other ListviewItem with the keyboard Key Down
I am new in universal apps with C# and Xaml,is it possible to do that??
thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Its totally possible. Subscribe to keyboard event:

`Window.Current.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.AcceleratorKeyActivated += CoreDispatcher_AcceleratorKeyActivated;`

```
private void CoreDispatcher_AcceleratorKeyActivated(CoreDispatcher sender, AcceleratorKeyEventArgs e)
{
    //Handle keyboard here
}
```

And set selected index of your list view to next item in the list.